# Java - Eclipse, dejo de permitir poner breakpoints

Tags: java, eclipse

soy nuevo aqui. Tengo un problema en Java, especificamente en el IDE Eclipse (Oxigen.2). Hasta ayer podia poner breakpoints, hoy no. Tengo la maquina freezada, supuestamente no deberia haber cambiado la configuracion de Eclipse. El mouse y el teclado andan bien. Simplemente hago doble click en el margen izquierdo y los Breakpoints no aparecen. Tambien he probado medios alternativos, como Run > Toggle BreakPoint (aparece grisado) o ctrl + Shift + B. Nada. Ningun mensaje de error.
¿Alguien que conozca a fondo la interface tiene alguna idea?

Answer (score 0):

ya lo solucione. La solucion provino de que los otros proyectos permitian debugear.
Asi que lo que hice fue copiar el codigo, cerrar el IDE, volverlo a abrir, crear un nuevo proyecto java y pegar el codigo con el nombre de las clases cambiado.
A partir de alli el debugeo funciono.